# Find the derivative of the function $(1 + 5x)e^{-5x}$

Tags: calculus

We have to find the derivative of the function $y=(1+5x)e^{-5x}$. The answer is $-25xe^{-5x}$. If you could explain/show how to do this, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It is a combination of the product rule, and the composition rule: $(fog)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the Product Rule: $$y=f(x)g(x), \space y' = f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x)$$
Where $$f(x) = 1+5x, \space g(x) = e^{-5x}$$
$$\implies y' = (1+5x) \cdot (e^{-5x})' + e^{-5x} \cdot (1+5x)'$$

For the differential of $g(x) = e^{-5x}$, use Chain Rule:

$$((f\circ g)x)' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

When differentiating the exponential function $e^x$, you have to differentiate '$e^x$' as well as the function in the power. So the differential of $e^x$ is actually $e^x \cdot(x)'$ but since the differential of $x$ is $1$, $\frac{dy}{dx} e^x = e^x$. For $e^{-5x}$ however, the function in the power $-5x$, has to be differentiated as well. Therefore, using the Chain Rule, $f'(g(x)) = (e^{-5x})'$ *which is just ($e^{-5x}$)* and $g'(x) = (-5x)'$ *which is just $-5$*.

$$\therefore (e^{-5x})' = (e^{-5x})' \cdot (-5x)' = e^{-5x} \cdot -5 = -5e^{-5x}$$

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Thanks :)

Comment: can you please explain this further? Thank you.

Comment: @kpatel20 I explained in the answer..Is that any better?

Comment: the answer I have is actually -25e^−5x. Is your answer just simplified? Thank you and sorry for the repeated questions.

Comment: Well that's just part of the answer..I left the product rule part (the first part of the answer) for you to do...The Chain Rule part was simply to explain finding the derivative of $e^{-5x}$. Plug $-5e^{-5x}$ into the $y'$ equation, calculate the other necessary derivative and simplify and you will get $-25e^{-5x}$. And its not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

product rule d(uv)/dx = u'v+uv'

```
y' = 5*e^(-5x)+-5*e^(-5x)*(1+5x)
```

Answer (score 0):

First,let $y=(1+5x)e^{-5x}$. notice that $(lny)'=\frac{1}{y}*y'$.
$$ln[(1+5x)e^{-5x}]=ln(1+5x)+ln(e^{-5x})=ln(1+5x)-5x$$
Then we get$$\{ln[(1+5x)e^{-5x}]\}'=\frac{5}{1+5x}-5=\frac{1}{(1+5x)e^{-5x}}*y'$$
$y'$ is easy to get.